# Computation of qubits with quantum gates using density matrix form

Tags: quantum-gate, simulation, density-matrix

I'm making a quantum circuit with qubits and quantum gates. While I'm doing it, I have some problem with it. My calculation process is below.
[image]

As you can see, start qubit is $|0 \rangle$ and after 'X' gate, the result will be $|1 \rangle$. And I checked if the result of quantum circuit and density matrix form of $|1 \rangle$ are different. As you can see, they are different.

Here are my questions.

1. Why it occurs?
2. If they are different, is my calculation wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you evolve a pure state under the action of a gate $U$, it evolves from
$$
|\psi\rangle\rightarrow U|\psi\rangle.
$$
However, a density matrix such as $\rho=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ evolves differently. You must calculate
$$
\rho\rightarrow U\rho U^\dagger.
$$
So, in this case, you must calculate
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right).
$$

Comment: Thank you for reply. Why we have to multiply conjugate transpose matrix? I wonder the reason. Could you tell me about it?

Comment: Simply because the bra of $U|\psi\rangle$ is $(U|\psi\rangle)^\dagger = \langle \psi |U^\dagger$. Therefore the evolution $|\psi\rangle\mapsto U|\psi\rangle$ is in the density matrix picture $|\psi\rangle\langle \psi |\mapsto U|\psi\rangle\langle \psi |U^\dagger$

Comment: Could you be more in detail? I can't understand now.

Comment: You know that to convert a state $|\psi\rangle$ into a density matrix, you rewrite it as $\rho=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$. How do you rewrite the state $U|\psi\rangle$ as a density matrix?

Comment: Okay! I got this. Thank you